# Google Maps in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer

Kind of stuck here. I am adding a very simple google map to my webpage, and using the basic javascript API to do so. Everything works fine in chrome, but with internet explorer it works occasionally. The error that comes up is:

> SCRIPT5022: InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function  js, line 102
>   character 390

the error refers to the call to google maps API, not in my js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Under Construction</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/betterlogo.ico" type="image/x-icon">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/thumbnails.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <!-- JS -->

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src='js/device.min.js'></script>
</head>
```

```
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

<--some more code filler that nobody needs to see,-->

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDFmJX1o4ocAPluAPlDWlh-VX_35iwc23o&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

and my javascript:

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat:40.4917507, lng:-74.2971267};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
  center: myLatLng,
  zoom: 15
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map:map,
    title:"abc"
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function(){
    var center=map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);
  })
}
```

Comment: Check for your browser version of IE.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport#desktop

Comment: Are you running a supported version of IE?

Comment: what warranted the downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I moved my main.js file above the call to the googlemaps API and it fixed the problem. I am assuming that the the call was being made before all my javascript loaded, hence the callback to the mapsInit didn't exist yet. Would love some feedback if my thinking is correct/incorrect. Thanks

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDFmJX1o4ocAPluAPlDWlh-VX_35iwc23o&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: same issue I'm having except that my actual init map was on the page and underneath it is the call to googleapis

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error as above, but the marked answer didn't help. If anyone is getting the `initMap` error only on Internet explorer it could be because you are using JavaScript that is too modern for Internet Explorer including 'template literals' and 'arrow functions'. I went through my code and replaced them with older code which removed this error. Hopefully that will save someone the hours of debugging I went through...